# How do I disable ECMAScript _vit_bin/services for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, web-services, sharepoint-2010

Currently we are not using the ECMAScript client OM and we don't want to for our implementation. Is there a way to turn it off globally?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think SharePoint uses the ECMAScript client OM internally for things like the ribbon, dialogs, and notifications. An easy way to check is to temporarily remove sp.js, sp.core.js and sp.runtime.js (plus the debug versions) from your _layoyts folder. If everything keeps working you've got a solution. If things start breaking due to the internal dependencies I mentioned then you'll have to explore alternative methods to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Ah, sorry Rob, I didn't enter all my information. We have a custom master page and we are not using those js files anyways. We handle everything thru custom webparts. However the REST service _vti_bin/ListData.svc is still available if you put it in the URL and this is bad news bears. I need/want to shut down the webservices all together or only allow a specific user to access it.